# Double quotes while putting the string into HTML through JavaScipt

Tags: javascript, string, double-quotes, bootbox

I have added a small snippet of java script call underneath:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" title="${tasksList[val]["command"]}"
                                    onclick="bootbox.alert({
                                        size: 'large',
                                        title: 'Job Command',
                                        message: '<pre>' + this.title + '</pre>'
                                    });">
                                    Job Command
                                </button></td>
```

the message looks like `ssh serverdomain`
However, when I do:

```
 console.log(tasksList[val]["command"])
```

it shows the correct output i.e

> ssh serverdomain "java -jar /local/folder --date=20190812"

I believe that the double quotes in the final output create some problem. Anyone knows how to get this correct? main focus should be `this.title` from the first code snippet.

It works fine for strings with no double quotes in there.

Comment: double quotes and single quotes are interchangeable in javasctipt and html ... so if you want nested quotes, use `"blah'blah'blah"` or  `'blah"blah"blah'` - in short, change `"command"` to `'command'`

Comment: title='${tasksList[val]["command"]}' with single quotes instead of double quotes title="${tasksList[val]["command"]}"

Comment: [Don't use inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045). They have too many problems: they have a demented scope chain (which requires global pollution), and they have string escaping issues. Use `addEventListener` instead

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replying everyone. I realized either way I will be debating with having " or ' in my final message. Since the command is not given by me, it can change in future. I made a solution that I think will help overcome in both situations. Please let me know if this can be a wring solution.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" title="${tasksList[val]["command"].replace(/\"/g, "&quot;")}"
                                    onclick="bootbox.alert({
                                        size: 'large',
                                        title: 'Job Command',
                                        message: '<pre>' + this.title + '</pre>'
                                        });">
                                    Job Command
                                </button>
```

Comment: I believe this will work given the function of bootbox. This, then, is the answer for all scenarios with double quotes you might have.